# Assigning users to GitHub Projectv2 Draft Issues

Tags: github, graphql, github-api

I'm trying to update the assignee list for a GitHub ProjectV2 draft issue with my organization installation app using the [updateProjectV2DraftIssue](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/mutations#updateprojectv2draftissue) mutation but I keep getting as response of:

```json
{
    "data": {
        "updateProjectV2DraftIssue": null
    },
    "errors": [
        {
            "type": "NOT_FOUND",
            "path": [
                "updateProjectV2DraftIssue"
            ],
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 1,
                    "column": 12
                }
            ],
            "message": "Could not resolve to DraftIssue node with the global id of '<ISSUE_ID>'."
        }
    ]
}
```

(where `<ISSUE_ID>` was the global node ID of the issue).

I also get the exact same issue when trying to add/remove assignees from an `Assignable` Issue/Pull Requests too when using the [addAssigneesToAssignable](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/mutations#addassigneestoassignable) mutation

I know that the node ID is correct as I'm using the value directly from a previous request that created the draft issue.

The mutation I am using is:

```
{
    "query":"mutation {
        updateProjectV2DraftIssue(
            input: {
                draftIssueId : \"<ISSUE_ID>\"
                assigneeIds : [
                    \"<USER_ID>\" 
                ] 
            } 
        ) {
            draftIssue {
                assignees(first: 100) {
                    nodes {
                        login  
                    } 
                }
            } 
        } 
    }" 
}
```

(where `USER_ID` is replaced with the User global node ID and `ISSUE_ID` with the issue global Node ID)

I'm unsure if this is an issue with my query or with the permissions of my Installation App. The current permissions it has are Repo: `Metadata: read`, `Issues: read & write`, `Pull requests: read & write` and Org: `Projects: admin`, `Members: read`